# Removing dependency of MSVCR120D.dll

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll, linker-errors

I have a dll (C/C++) built using VS2013 which is used by an exe, let me call it exe_1  to call another exe, exe_2.

The same code (&the def file) was used to built a dll on VS 6 many years back & it works perfectly so that exe_1 uses- > old_dll  - >invokes exe_2

Now the problem is that the new dll is having some issues so that it is not invoking the exe_2 mentioned above. I have the source codes for both dll & exe_2 but not exe_1. Hence I used some DebugBreak statements to check whether exe_2 is getting invoked by exe_1, but result was negative.

Here are the differences I can find across my new dll (VS 2013) & the old dll (VS 6)

1. The "dumpbin /exports" for the new & old dll have some variations in the Summary section as below (exports section have the same function names for both):

New dll Summary

```
    6000 .data
    1000 .idata
    C000 .rdata
    4000 .reloc
    1000 .rsrc
   5F000 .text
   2F000 .textbss
```

Old Dll Summary

```
    C000 .data
    6000 .rdata
    3000 .reloc
    1000 .rsrc
   2F000 .text
```

2. If we see the Profile output for **old dll** (using the Dependency Walker Profiling), the below warnings are extra

Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

3. Using Dependency walker I found out that my **new dll** have one additional dependency  MSVCR120D.dll.

Since I felt that point #3 is the culprit, I tried many options to remove that dependency by specifying /Mtd (also tried /Mt) option under C/C++ - > Code Generation - > Runtime Library .

But all I get is some unresolved Linker errors for _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks, _CrtMemCheckpoint, __free_dbg e.t.c & hence I am unable to generate the new dll with this option.

Please provide your inputs on this.

Comment: Compile the release version of the DLL. `MSVCR120D.dll` suggests that the new dll has been built as debug version.

Comment: I have just looked in my Windows 7 system folders, there are 32 and 64 bit versions of `MSVCR120.dll` but not `MSVCR120D.dll`

Comment: Release Built also throws these linker errors mercilessly. I verified that I have a _DEBUG flag based on which certain code portions are included which uses the _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks e.t.c. Even after removing that Preprocessor flag from the Release configuration I am getting the same Linker error

Comment: Hi all, I have solved this particular issue. We have to check for the additional dll's which have been included for building the new dll , to ensure they are also built using the same flags /MtD e.t.c.